# Aurelia Server Side Rendering - Avoid unnecessary client-side api calls

Tags: aurelia, server-side-rendering

I have an [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io) application based on Aurelia CLI 1.2.x and Webpack 4, and using Server Side Rendering because search engine indexation is essential.

About 160+ pages are text-only pages; those would normally be static pages, but the content is actually retrieved from a database.

Since these pages are managed through a CMS and many can be added at will, I have a catch-all module in Aurelia that takes care of fetching the content and displaying it.

`catch-all.js`:

```js
import { I18N } from 'aurelia-i18n';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { StaticContent } from "plugin/static-content/static-content";
import { StaticContentService } from "plugin/service-model";
import { Router } from "aurelia-router";

@inject(StaticContentService, I18N, Router)
export class CatchAll {
  constructor(staticContentService, i18n, router) {
    this._staticContentService = staticContentService;
    this.language = i18n.getLocale();
    this.router = router;
  }

  async canActivate(params) {
    const path = params.path;

    let result = await StaticContent.isStaticContent(path, this._staticContentService, this.language);
    if (result) {
      this.page = PLATFORM.moduleName("static-content");
      this.context = result;
    }

    if (!this.page) {
      this.router.navigateToRoute("not-found");
    }
  }
}
```

With a very simple html counterpart, `catch-all.html`:

```html
<template>
  <compose view-model.bind="page" model.bind="context"></compose>
</template>
```

The static method `StaticContent.isStaticContent` is where the actual html content of the page is fetched:

```js
static async isStaticContent(path, staticContentService, language) {
  try {
    let url = path.slice(1);
    let page = await staticContentService.getByUrl(url, language);

    if (!page) {
      return false;
    }

    return { page: page };
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
    return e;
  }
}
```

And the `catch-all` module is configured in `app.js` as follows:

```js
config.mapUnknownRoutes(navigationInstruction => {
   return { moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName("catch-all") };
});
```

Like I said, this is based on Aurelia's Server Side Rendering approach using `Koa`, `aureliaKoaMiddleware`, etc.

### The Problem

This approach works properly, and if I inspect the network tab, the very first request return the fully rendered html. 
After that, various requests are made by the client to get images, etc, but one of the lasts requests is to `staticContentService.getByUrl(url, language)` *to get the content of the page again*.

This does not only seems like a waste, but it's penalising SEO-wise.

Is there a way, either Aurelia-specific or generic Node.js, to transfer this pre-rendered content from the ssr-rendered html to the client call?

I know ReactJs has built-in ways to handle this, and Angular 5+ has the "State Transfer API" that takes care of exactly this problem.

Comment: Nice to see you got it working for you. For the static content, is there a chance that you could serialize those content into the page and get it from there later when dydrating the page instead of making a request?

Comment: Thanks @bigopon. I have access to the pre-rendered html in Koa after pre-rendering. (in `server.js`). But I am not sure on how I kan reuser it later when Aurelia "paints" the app. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe something like this: `let page = await (window.languageJson || staticContentService.getByUrl(url, language));`

Comment: Interesting. Will `window` be available while running in Koa, though? I'll give it a go and report back so you can get your answer points if it works ;)

Comment: window should be made available globally by aurelia - pal - nodejs, during bootstrapping I believe. If not, you can easily do so in your entry script.
Even if it's not, then it could just be an element with huge amount of text inside it, or its attribute to be extracted

Comment: FYI @bigopon, I've tried setting the content in a viarable in `PLATFORM.global.window` on the SSR pass, but that variable is empty when the client re-renders. Back to the drawing board, I guess.

Comment: we can also serialize the json into an attribute of an element of the the page. Did you try that?

Comment: Hi @bigopon, sorry for not replying to your comment before. Lots of things have been taking priority. I did **not** try that, not even sure how I would go about it, exactly...